# Running OpenShift Origin directly on hardware?

Tags: openstack, cloud, openshift-origin

To anyone with OpenShift Origin experience, is there any benefit in skipping any IaaS infrastructure (like OpenStack), and installing the PaaS layer right on top of hardware?

What would be the upsides and downsides of such approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

(disclaimer: I work at Gigaspaces, developing Cloudify.)

IMO, it truly depends on your needs, and on the private/public nature of your IaaS solution. IaaS could give you access to hardware without having to actually purchase it, and will surely give you elasticity. However, if you have expected and fixed environment requirements - IaaS could be an overkill.

Another issue is the nature of your IT maintenance. IaaS could take your IT team one step away from physically dealing with hardware, which is an upside if you're currently putting too much time or money into it. Note that if you're implementing a private ("in-house") IaaS solution you might actually create additional IT challenges for your staff.

IaaS is always another "middleman" managing your business, meaning you have less control, and sometimes less security if it's a remote solution.

Another consideration is stability - IaaS relies on VMs, which are not as stable as physical machines.

Cloudify supports both options, and our [PaaS-on-hardware](http://www.cloudifysource.org/guide/2.2/setup/configuring_byon.html) solution is called BYON ("Bring Your Own Node"). It might be what you're looking for or just a temp environment before going IaaS, it's your call.